# scale in Circular plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scale

I want to know how you can generate a scale as this picture, I am currently doing a similar figure but the scale is the only thing I can't handle.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Please be more precise in what scales you mean and what exactly the problem is with these scales. (e.g., the angular or radial position scales / axes? Is labelling the problem or something else?) Also, if you could illustrate the problem with a reproducible example and/or a plot that would be helpful for us to see the issue.

Comment: iris %>% gather(dim, val, -Species) %>%
  group_by(dim, Species) %>% summarise(val = mean(val)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(dim, val, group=Species, col=Species)) + 
    geom_line(size=2) + coord_polar()

Comment: and by scale I mean a "symmetrical" scale sequence from 2 to 2 with the center in -2.

Comment: She had exactly the same problem but no one replied! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807846/ggplot2-axis-for-polar-plot

Comment: @GilbertoDuránBishop I've answered the [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63827375/8449629) if you are still interested.